# Meteor iOS Can't Insert

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, meteor

I'm building an iOS app with swift that hits a meteor backend using https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios. Sign in and signup seem to work fine, but inserting a document in CoreData doesn't seem to update the server. Here's my iOS code:

```
let managedObjectContext = meteor.mainQueueManagedObjectContext

let event = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("UserEvent", inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext) as! UserEvent
event.name = self.nameTextField.text
do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.domain)")
}
```

Adding stuff in the web interface to the `UserEvents` collection on the web works just fine.

Hopefully I'm missing something simple. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code describes a local save not a server save.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is definitely a local save to coredata, but all the sample code shows the local cache saves being propagated automatically, or so I thought.

Comment: I got it working by switching to Objective-DDP. It seems like a more robust library with less magic.